# Proper way to identify static cells in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view controller and I overrode this function:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
    }
```

My cell identifier is `myCell`. I created 4 static cells, and went into each cell and gave each the identifier `myCell`. However, this crashes due to not recognizing the cell identifier. However, if I change to dynamic prototypes, give the cell the `myCell` identifier, it works as intended. I guess this will do for now...as I can just tell it dynamically how many cells I want. But I'm really interested to find out why my static cells aren't working with the same exact method. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay thanks @Rob, you can post an answer if you want and I will accept :)

Answer (score 0):

When you have static cells (i.e. a small, fixed set of static cells, rather than dynamic cells with cell prototypes where you control how many of which types of cells will be dynamically generated), you shouldn’t implement any of the [`UITableViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) methods. Just create `IBOutlet` references for the various controls you have in your static cells and update them just like you would if you weren’t using a `UITableView` at all.

---

As an aside, if you were using dynamic cells, you would never give two different cell prototypes the same reuse identifier. The purpose of the reuse identifier is to let it know which cell prototype to use, and it wouldn’t therefore make any sense to give multiple cell prototypes the same identifier.